# Rails : Database Seed

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, seed

I have a rails app in which there is a lot of data in the database. I have come to realise that on heroku only PostgreSQL is supported. Now my database is MySQL. Is there any way I can get rails to copy all the data from the database into the seed file without me having to type everything out by hand?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to export to seed.rb, but you may can export the MySQL data to SQL, and then import it into PostgreSQL. Have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884060/is-there-a-free-tool-to-convert-mysql-dump-to-postgres)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No rails does not have the ability to do that.

You can look into the [mysqltopostgres](https://github.com/maxlapshin/mysql2postgres) gem. This blog entry covers the usage pretty well. http://onestoryeveryday.com/mysql-to-postgresql-conversionmigration.html

Answer (score 0):

Heroku supports MySQL with the [ClearDB addon](https://addons.heroku.com/cleardb).